# RecordRTC with sending video chunks to server and record as webm or mp4 on server side

Tags: javascript, socket.io, video-streaming, recordrtc

Hi everyone. Currently I am developing a function that can record on buffer array with each chunk by using dataonavailable function in RecordRTC instead of stopping the record and sending it back to the server. However, when I send it to the server through socket.emit as an encoded64 data or bufferArray, the final video is corrupted under three extensions: x-matroska(MKV), mp4, webM. Therefore, can I ask the **reasons why the file is ending up corrupted** and how will I be able to fix this issue?

**FYI regarding webRTC:** Here is the documentation that you can read more about it: https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC

**P/S:** I used timesplice of 1000 and stop early from 5-10s and still cannot record as a short video.

**Server - Code:**

```
socket.on("SEND BLOB",buffer=>{
        function writeOrAppendData(data){
            var filePath = './'
            const fileExtension = '.webm'
            if (!fs.existsSync(filePath+'finalresult' + fileExtension)){
                console.log('write Original file')
                fs.writeFileSync(filePath+'finalresult' + fileExtension,data)
            }
            else {
                fs.appendFileSync(filePath+'finalresult' + fileExtension,data)
            }
        }
        console.log(buffer)
        if (buffer instanceof Buffer)
            writeOrAppendData(buffer)


    })
```

**Client - code:**

```
const config = ({video:true,audio:true})
      this.setState({RTCStatus:"pending"})
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(config).then( async stream=>{
          const candidateURL = this.candidateID
          const socketIO = io.connect(baseURL,{query: {candidateID:candidateURL }})
          //this.socketRef = io.connect(baseURL);
          this.stream = stream;
          this.socketRef.current = socketIO;
          //this.candidateVideoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
          this.screenSharingStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(config);
          this.videoRecorder = new RecordRTC(this.screenSharingStream, {
            type: 'video',
            mimeType:"video/webm;codecs=avc1",
            //disableLogs: true,
            timeSlice: 1000,
            bitsPerSecond: 128000,
            ondataavailable:async function(blob) {
              console.log(blob)
              
              //var candidateVideo = document.getElementById('candidate-video')
              
              //candidateVideo.src =URL.createObjectURL(blob)
              console.log(candidateVideo)
             // this.candidateVideoRef.current.srcObject = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob)
              reader.onloadend = function(){
                var buffer = reader.result;
                console.log(buffer)
                socketIO.emit('SEND BLOB',buffer)
              }
              //let blobData = await fetch(blob).then(r => r.blob()).then(blobFile => new File([blobFile], "record", { type: "video/mp4" }))
              //console.log(blobData)
              
            },
            
        });
          console.log('hey')
          this.videoRecorder.startRecording();
          this.setState({RTCStatus:this.videoRecorder.getState()})
///const sleep = m => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, m));
          //await sleep(3000);
          
          //this.videoRecorder.stopRecording(async function(){
          //  
          //  socketIO.emit('END BLOB')
          //})//
          
    
  }
RTCStop = () =>{
    if (this.stream && this.screenSharingStream){
      const candidateURL = this.candidateID
      const socketIO = io.connect(baseURL,{query: {candidateID:candidateURL }})
      this.stream.getTracks().forEach((track)=>{
        if (track.readyState==='live') {
            track.stop()
            this.candidateVideoRef.current.style.display='none';
            this.videoRecorder.stopRecording(async function(){
              socketIO.emit('END BLOB')
              //let blob = await fetch(this.videoRecorder.getBlob()).then(r => r.blob()).then(blobFile => new File([blobFile], "record", { type: "video/mp4" }))
              //let blobDuration = await getBlobDuration(blob);
              //console.log(blobDuration+'seconds')
              //let data = new FormData()
              //console.log(blob);
              //data.append("videoDuration",blobDuration)
              //data.append(this.candidateID, blob)
              //console.log('axios not run');
              //await request().post('/c/video', data)
              //console.log('axios run');
              //let rest = await
              //this.setState({submitVideo: true})
            })
        }})
```

Comment: An update from me is that I change to recordmedia, which is not superior to webRTC (real time and promising browser support) with the same function ( this time I use encode64 to send data and use writestream to write to my local file). Therefore, can I ask the different between WebRTC and Record Media in streaming data and how does file end up corrupted in webRTC

Comment: Another questions come from me is that after I add the video stream to add tracks with the audio stream from the getusermedia, it encounters the previous problem: the corrupted video. Therefore, can I ask about what have I done wrong in the streaming process ?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into a similar issue with using recordRTC. I'm pretty sure the reason the files are getting corrupted are because when sending chunks that have been recorded the chunked video files need specific meta data in order to be decoded. That meta data is found on the first chunk that is recorded. So when trying to play back the video if they are not combined into one video file they will show up as corrupted. I got around this by combinging all the chunks into one blob.

```
async function mergeChunksAndPlay() {
  console.log(chunks, "vid chuncks");
  const blobs = chunks.map(chunk => chunk.blob);
  const mergedBlob = new Blob(blobs, { type: 'video/webm' });
  const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(mergedBlob);
  downloadBlob(mergedBlob, `merged-video-${Date.now()}.webm`);

}

function downloadBlob(blob, filename) {
  const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
  downloadLink.href = blobUrl;
  downloadLink.download = filename; // Provide a filename for the download

  // Append the link to the document and trigger the download
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click();

  // Clean up by revoking the blob URL and removing the link
  URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
  document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

This will work if you have saved in all the chunks into an array called "chunks" and it will download the merged file to your browser. You should be able to play it from there.